# Extract Url using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've been searching for at least 2hrs but I can't find any pattern to extract following Urls using regex. I went with too many patterns which described in many articles. But I couldn't find something useful.

For Example : Urls like following patterns.

```
http://google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.image.google.com
http://google.com:8080
http://google.com:8080/default.aspx?param=1
http://google.com/default.aspx?param=1&param1=2
```

**Update :** Dear friends, It looks like I have to explain my issue in more details, I'm working on a simple proxy server using TCP components, My server listen to specific port when an incoming connection received. I'm extracting and reading all client request data.
data contains headers and content types and etc like following :

```
GET http://www.bing.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,fa;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.bing.com
DNT: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

These are plain-text so I need to find and extract Urls for doing forwarding operations.

And any Url pattern you guess.
Please, Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Extracting them from where? Extracting what from them?

Comment: What kind of string? Any examples?

Comment: @Oded For example WebRequest headers contain Host : 'http://google.com'. I want to extract them from WebRequest headers.

Comment: Can't you use the `Uri` class instead of regex in this case?

Comment: @eyossi: First I've to find the Uri.

Comment: This is still not very informative - if you have the headers, I would assume you could parse for the specific header that contains the URL. Also, a Regex should be tailored to the data being searched, so without a complete example of inputs and outputs it is difficult to give you a good answer.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you need to extract ? What do you expect from the url ? Domains ? user/password ? port ? non-http url (ftp://) ? real domain or also "fake ones" ? path ? query parameters ? non standard query parameters ? etc, etc, etc. That's why you encountered so many patterns, because depending on what you need, it's not the same one.

Comment: And what do you expect to extract from that? The URL on the GET? The one against Host? Something else? Something more? What about requests that have parameters on the URL?

Comment: @Oded It's not working, Let me ask you How do you handle this situation if you were instead of me.

Comment: What's not working? You have not given a complete description of the problem yet. I am not able to give you any sort of answer without the _complete_ details I have asked (you gave a single example, didn't explain the expected output, didn't give a more complex example either).

Comment: I need a pattern to find urls in a plain-text. I described my problem.

Comment: You have described the problem in vague terms (that could apply to a book about the web, a bookmark file, an HTML page and many others). You want a solution that will fit your specific problem - you need to state the problem with enough detail for others to be able to give you an appropriate answer.

Comment: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/

Comment: In regards to narrowing it down to headers - you didn't explain what headers, what form the result should be in and what a more complex URL and set of headers should be parsed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`https?://[\w\.]+\.\w+(:\d{1,5})?(/[\w?&.=]+)?`

Answer (score 0):

Salam. Try this one:

```
https?://[^\s]+
```